# Python development, creating a global class object

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm unsure whether this is something that is *ok* to do in terms of development, or something I should avoid in Python. I have a class structure like

```
Main GUI Class
    Has a Draw Manager object

Draw Manager Class
    Has a Database Manager object

Database Manager Object
    ....
```

The thing is I want my database manager to be completely independent from my other program functionality, so anything database related is completely encapsulated in one class. But if I want just one object that other classes will call to e.g.

```
Main GUI Class

    def displayDatabase(self):
        databaseObject.getJSON()

Draw Manager Class

    def drawPolygon(self):
        polygonObj = Polygon(...)
        # draw polygon
        databaseObject.notifyAdd(polygonObj)
```

Is it ok to simply create the class, and declare an object below it which will be used the entire program?

```
# dbmanage.py
Database Manager Class

     ...

dbManager = Database ManagerClass ()
```

Then in my other files, simply include the object?

```
# drawmanage.py
from dbmanage import dbManager

...

# mainwindow.py
from dbmanage import dbManager

...

if __name__ == "__main__":

    ...
```

Is this a sound design? Or is this bad programming / a bad thing to do in general?

Comment: My initial reaction was "you should use dependency injection for that," but Python's dynamic nature means this basically *is* dependency injection (or at least, it's flexible enough to become dependency injection if and when you need it).  All the same, you might want to have [a function that returns the manager class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) instead of just making it a global variable.

Comment: @Kevin how about for python 2.7

Comment: Functions exist in 2.7.  I'm just giving an example of how this pattern has been used in 3.4.

Comment: Feels like something for `classmethods`...

Comment: I know I would rather create the DatabaseManager in main GUI init and find a way to pass it to other object. Maybe you can read: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/